# Including MathJax JS-Scripts only for some content files in a CMS

Tags: javascript, php, include, mathjax

I want to add this lines only for some content files in my own CMS footer.

Lines for using MathJax

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});</script>
<script async type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

At the end of every content file I have this line for the footer and other stuff:

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/data/after_content.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a simple solution.

At the end of each content file:

in my footer file:

```
if (isset($mathjax)) {
    echo "<script type=\"text/x-mathjax-config\"> MathJax.Hub.Config({TeX:{extensions: [\"mhchem.js\"]}, tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\\(','\\\)']]}});</script>\n";
    echo '<script  type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>'."\n";
}
```